# Codeigniter 4 csrf filter for post methods in given area only

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

*app/Config/Filters.php*

You can set filter for all post methods

```
public $methods = [
    'post' => ['filter'],
];
```

Or you can set a filter for a given area (but all methods)

```
public $filters = [
    'filter' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
];
```

How can I set a filter for **only post methods** in a given area? Or even better **in all areas except one**?

I know it is possible for individuals endpoint routes, but I am hoping to find more of a global solution..

Comment: [From the docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#enable-csrf-protection): "*Select URIs can be whitelisted from CSRF protection (for example API endpoints expecting externally POSTed content). You can add these URIs by adding them as exceptions in the filter: ...*".  Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It is, but I feel like that it would enable it not only for post, but other methods aswell. Also I assumed that the $method config overrides the previous configs, or perhaps I can combine both of them?..

Comment: I tried to combine the $global with $method and it seems like the latter overrides the previous. As in csrf for post ignores the exceptions in global..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  The text I quoted here from the docs is about **excluding** URIs from CSRF protection, by adding them to the `except` array.  Your question says "*in all areas except one*", so I thought this is what you are trying to do.  `except` also supports regular expressions, so you could exclude a pattern.  Regarding methods - at the top of that docs page it says: "*The CSRF Protection is only available for POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests. Requests for other methods are not protected.*"

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, but the URI exclusion is only one part. The problem is to combine it with a specific request method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, not tested but it should work.

Create a new filter which extended from CSRF and checks request method

```
namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Config\Services;
use Exception;

class CustomCSRF extends CSRF implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $request = parent::before($request, $arguments);
        try {
            if ($request->getMethod() != "post") {
                throw new Exception("Wrong method");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Services::response()
                ->setJSON([
                    'error' => $e->getMessage()
                ])
                ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return $request;
    }
}
```

then add it under filters for routes

```
public $aliases = [
    ...
    ...
    'customcsrf' => CustomCSRF::class
];

...
...

public $filters = [
    'customcsrf' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
];
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility, thank you. I was thinking that it's unnecessary load to check in every request if its a post, but I suppose that's the case in every scenario..

I'll see if anyone comes with another solution, otherwise I'll go with this one :)